# PHP - How to exit an if

Tags: php, if-statement

My code is showing an error in the line commented below saying:

- ErrorException A non-numeric value encountered

The input variable receives an asterisk character and runs through my if instead of stopping at the first iteration. Could you help me find out the reason for the error or tell me the command to exit if after the first if iteration?

```
   $minute = '*';

    $pos1 = strpos($minute, '*');
    $pos2 = strpos($minute, ',');
    $pos3 = strpos($minute, '-');
    $pos4 = strpos($minute, '/');

    if (true == $pos1) {
        $operator = '*';
    } elseif (true == $pos2) {
        $operator = ',';
    } elseif (true == $pos3) {
        $operator = '-';
    } elseif (true == $pos4) {
        $operator = '/';
    } else {
        $minute_atual = Carbon::now->format('i');

        if ($minute < $minute_current) {
            $minute = 60 - ($minute_current - $minute); // The error message says it is on that line
            $operator = $ minute;
        } elseif ($minute_current == $minute) {
            $minute = '0';
            $operator = $minute;
        } else {
            $minute = $minute - $minute_current;
            $operator = $minute;
                        }
    }
```

Comment: that was because your variable is string not an integer, try to parse it to integer..

Comment: `$ minute` !== `$minute;` in line `$operator = $ minute;`

Comment: The reason your statements are failing is likely due to `"[strpos] Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1. "` - so as you are trying to find if it is `true` you are equating `0==true` which will never be true... [view the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Please add the full code - with what you have shown there are several variables that are unknown so it is hard to answer. However, when you do `if ($minute < $minute_current) {` the var `$minute` is still a string `*`

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` is notorious for that error.

Indeed

```
$minute = "*";
$pos1 = strpos($minute, '*');
var_dump($pos1); 
// 0 because this is the first (0th) character
```

so the test `true == 0` fails

Use strict inequality `$pos0 !== false` instead

Function reference : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos
See the warning in the "return value" section.

Comment: Sometimes the error stays silent for a long time until it breaks your code. Here, the real error is that `"*"` should be catched by the first if. There, `"*"` goes in the "else" clause where you assume it will be a numeric value, and the `-` operator complains about it because you can't do `3 - "*"`. Just `var_dump($minute)` on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$minute = '*';
```

This is a string. And php can't apply numeric operations over it. I don't see if you are assigning a numeric value to it before the subtraction.

Basically you are trying to do "number - (number - string)". Probably you are missing some part of your logic.

Also you don't need to set priority over the operations if they are subtraction or addition.

```
60 - $minute_current - $minute
```

Will give you the same result. Of course if $minute is integer.

And also I strongly recommend to avoid weak comparison, use ===, !== instead. So you know exactly what you are doing